# How to make these menu items link to other pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, href

I am trying to make it that clicking anywhere on the coloured box for "home" will take you to yayitworks.html, but when I have said `<p href="yayitworks.html">HOME</p>`, it doesn't go to yayitworks.html when clicked. Being able to click on the actual text and go to yayitworks.html would be good, but it would be better to be able to just click anywhere on the box (generally better ux)

```js
var open = false;

function Drop(n) {
    var i;
    if (open == false) {
        for (i = n; i < 5; i++) {
            Drp(i)
        }
        open = true
    } else if (open == true) {
        for (i = n; i < 5; i++) {
            Cls(i)
        }
        open = false
    }
}

function Drp(n) {
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-con")[n];
    var pos = -1 * window.innerHeight - n * 100;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

    function frame() {
        if (pos >= -10) {
            clearInterval(id);
            elem.style.top = 0 + 'px';
        } else {
            pos += 10;
            elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
        }
    }
}

function Cls(n) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-con")[n];
    var poss = 0;
    var ids = setInterval(frames, 5);

    function frames() {
        if (poss <= -1 * window.innerHeight) {
            clearInterval(ids);
            elems.style.top = -1 * window.innerHeight + 'px';
        } else {
            poss += -7 - n * 2;
            elems.style.top = poss + 'px';
        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(background.png);
    background-color: black;
}

.menu-icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 10px 15px;
    transform: scale(0.8);
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 20
}

.menu-bar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 5px;
    background: rgb(190, 190, 190);
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:50px
}

.menu-bar1 {
    margin-top: 9px
}

.menu-bar2 {
    margin-top: 23px
}

.menu-bar3 {
    margin-top: 37px
}

.menu-icon.hover .menu-bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scaleX(0.7);
    margin-top: 22px;
}

.menu-icon.hover .menu-bar2 {
    opacity: 0
}

.menu-icon.hover .menu-bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) scaleX(0.7);
    margin-top: 22px;
}

.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.menu-con {
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    position: relative;
    top: -100%;
    transition: all 0.5s
}

.menu-con p:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.menu-con:hover p:before {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}

.menu-con p {
    height: 20px;
    -webkit-align-self: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .menu-con {
        min-width: 50%
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
    .menu-con {
        min-width: 100%
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Ben Cohen</title>
<link href=style.css rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="animate.css" rel=stylesheet>
<script src="main.js"></script>
           </head>
    <body>
<div class="menu-icon" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');Drop(0)">
    <div class="menu-bar menu-bar1"></div>
    <div class="menu-bar menu-bar2"></div>
    <div class="menu-bar menu-bar3"></div>
</div>
 
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-con" style="background:red;" href="yayitworks.html">
        <p>HOME</p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-con" style="background:blue">
        <p>PORTFOLIO</p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-con" style="background:darkorange;">
        <p>UNDECIDED</p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-con" style="background:green;">
        <p>HOMEWORK</p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-con" style="background:white;">
        <p style="color:black">TEST PAGE</p>
    </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `href` only works on a `a` tag. You have shown on `p` tag in the above description and `div` tag in the `code` sample. Try to change it to `a` tag and try

Comment: You cant have `href` attribute on anything but an `<a>`.

Comment: Hi Ben - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more I can help with, please add a comment below my answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you want to know. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer. *(You won't get any points for doing so, but that will close out the question.)* Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*First:* your class name is spelled incorrectly, it should be `menu-icon` not `menu-con`.

*Second:*
`<div class="menu-icon" style="background:red;" href="yayitworks.html">
 <p>HOME</p>
</div>`

This should be `<a>` tags, not `<div>`, like this:

`<a class="menu-icon" style="background:red;" href="yayitworks.html">
  <p>HOME</p>
</a>`

*Third:* Don't forget to add `display: block;` to your `.menu-icon` class in your CSS to have it act the same as it is currently.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `<p>` with `<a href="">` and also change `p` to `a` in **CSS** try this, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```js
var open = false;

function Drop(n) {
    var i;
    if (open == false) {
        for (i = n; i < 5; i++) {
            Drp(i)
        }
        open = true
    } else if (open == true) {
        for (i = n; i < 5; i++) {
            Cls(i)
        }
        open = false
    }
}

function Drp(n) {
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-con")[n];
    var pos = -1 * window.innerHeight - n * 100;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

    function frame() {
        if (pos >= -10) {
            clearInterval(id);
            elem.style.top = 0 + 'px';
        } else {
            pos += 10;
            elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
        }
    }
}

function Cls(n) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-con")[n];
    var poss = 0;
    var ids = setInterval(frames, 5);

    function frames() {
        if (poss <= -1 * window.innerHeight) {
            clearInterval(ids);
            elems.style.top = -1 * window.innerHeight + 'px';
        } else {
            poss += -7 - n * 2;
            elems.style.top = poss + 'px';
        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(background.png);
    background-color: black;
}

.menu-icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 10px 15px;
    transform: scale(0.8);
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 20
}

.menu-bar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 5px;
    background: rgb(190, 190, 190);
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:50px
}

.menu-bar1 {
    margin-top: 9px
}

.menu-bar2 {
    margin-top: 23px
}

.menu-bar3 {
    margin-top: 37px
}

.menu-icon.hover .menu-bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scaleX(0.7);
    margin-top: 22px;
}

.menu-icon.hover .menu-bar2 {
    opacity: 0
}

.menu-icon.hover .menu-bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) scaleX(0.7);
    margin-top: 22px;
}

.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.menu-con {
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    position: relative;
    top: -100%;
    transition: all 0.5s
}

.menu-con a:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.menu-con:hover a:before {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}

.menu-con a {
    height: 20px;
    -webkit-align-self: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    z-index: 2;
    text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .menu-con {
        min-width: 50%
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
    .menu-con {
        min-width: 100%
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Ben Cohen</title>
<link href=style.css rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="animate.css" rel=stylesheet>
<script src="main.js"></script>
           </head>
    <body>
<div class="menu-icon" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');Drop(0)">
    <div class="menu-bar menu-bar1"></div>
    <div class="menu-bar menu-bar2"></div>
    <div class="menu-bar menu-bar3"></div>
</div>
 
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-con" style="background:red;">
        <a href="yayitworks.html">HOME</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-con" style="background:blue">
        <a href="">PORTFOLIO</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-con" style="background:darkorange;">
        <a href="">UNDECIDED</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-con" style="background:green;">
        <a href="">HOMEWORK</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-con" style="background:white;">
        <a href="" style="color:black">TEST PAGE</a>
    </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The href attribute goes on the `<a>` tag, not a `<div>` tag. I updated your code to show you what that would look like.

```js
var open = false;

function Drop(n) {
    var i;
    if (open == false) {
        for (i = n; i < 5; i++) {
            Drp(i)
        }
        open = true
    } else if (open == true) {
        for (i = n; i < 5; i++) {
            Cls(i)
        }
        open = false
    }
}

function Drp(n) {
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-con")[n];
    var pos = -1 * window.innerHeight - n * 100;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

    function frame() {
        if (pos >= -10) {
            clearInterval(id);
            elem.style.top = 0 + 'px';
        } else {
            pos += 10;
            elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
        }
    }
}

function Cls(n) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-con")[n];
    var poss = 0;
    var ids = setInterval(frames, 5);

    function frames() {
        if (poss <= -1 * window.innerHeight) {
            clearInterval(ids);
            elems.style.top = -1 * window.innerHeight + 'px';
        } else {
            poss += -7 - n * 2;
            elems.style.top = poss + 'px';
        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(background.png);
    background-color: black;
}

.menu-icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 10px 15px;
    transform: scale(0.8);
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 20
}

.menu-bar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 5px;
    background: rgb(190, 190, 190);
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:50px
}

.menu-bar1 {
    margin-top: 9px
}

.menu-bar2 {
    margin-top: 23px
}

.menu-bar3 {
    margin-top: 37px
}

.menu-icon.hover .menu-bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scaleX(0.7);
    margin-top: 22px;
}

.menu-icon.hover .menu-bar2 {
    opacity: 0
}

.menu-icon.hover .menu-bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) scaleX(0.7);
    margin-top: 22px;
}

.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.menu-con {
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    position: relative;
    top: -100%;
    transition: all 0.5s
}

.menu-con p:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.menu-con:hover p:before {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}

.menu-con p {
    height: 20px;
    -webkit-align-self: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .menu-con {
        min-width: 50%
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
    .menu-con {
        min-width: 100%
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Ben Cohen</title>
<link href=style.css rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="animate.css" rel=stylesheet>
<script src="main.js"></script>
           </head>
    <body>
<div class="menu-icon" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');Drop(0)">
    <div class="menu-bar menu-bar1"></div>
    <div class="menu-bar menu-bar2"></div>
    <div class="menu-bar menu-bar3"></div>
</div>
 
<div class="menu">
    <a href="yayitworks.html">
        <div class="menu-con" style="background:red;">
            <p>HOME</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="menu-con" style="background:blue">
        <p>PORTFOLIO</p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-con" style="background:darkorange;">
        <p>UNDECIDED</p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-con" style="background:green;">
        <p>HOMEWORK</p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-con" style="background:white;">
        <p style="color:black">TEST PAGE</p>
    </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You *can* put a div inside an a-tag, since HTML5. See this reference:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-entire-div-clickable/